# What info can we get once user grants access for App?

Tags: facebook

In regards to the above, what info can we get?
And how to get retrieve them for our app?
Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you dont ask for the extended permission then you get the simple information about user like name, sex, DOB profile pic etc. But if you ask for the extended permission you can get the information about what you ask. For example if you ask the extended permission of email you can get user email, if you get the extended permission of user_photos you can get the all uploaded photos of a user, if you get the extended permission of publish stream you can publish any thing on user wall. You can get a list of extended permissions from [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)